# Map nested array with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I'm trying to map a nested array using .map(), so I could display and pinpoint all London underground locations in a map.

```
this.undergroundGeoJson = [
        {
            'type': 'FeatureCollection',

            'crs': { 'type': 'name', 'properties': { 'name': 
            'urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84' } },

            'features': [
                {
                    'type': 'Feature',
                    'geometry': {
                        'type': 'Point',
                        'coordinates': [-0.278126, 51.5025]
                    },
                    'properties': {
                        'name': 'Acton Town'
                    }
                },
                {
                    'type': 'Feature',
                    'geometry': {
                        'type': 'Point',
                        'coordinates': [-0.263033174, 51.50883531]
                    },
                    'properties': {
                        'name': 'Acton Central'
                    }
                },
                {
                    'type': 'Feature',
                    'geometry': {
                        'type': 'Point',
                        'coordinates': [-0.262879534, 51.50856013]
                    },
                    'properties': {
                        'name': 'Acton Central'
                    }
                }
           }
       ]
```

I need the coordinates array elements down in the geometry obj.

this is my code so far...

```
@computed
    get undergroundLatLongs() {
    return this.undergroundGeoJson.map((u) =>
    [u.features.geometry.coordinates[0], 
    u.features.geometry.coordinates[1]]);
}
```

and this is the error log...

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'coordinates' of undefined
```

any help welcomed.

Comment: Provide sample output that you want

Comment: `feautres` is an array, not an object, so you can't use object notation for it. It should be something like `features[0].geometry`

Comment: As pointed out by Jayce444, you need a index into the features array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`features` is an array and you need to access it using `index`

```
 u.features[i].geometry.coordinates[0]
           ^^^
```

```js
const undergroundGeoJson =[{'type':'FeatureCollection','crs':{'type':'name','properties':{'name':'urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84'}},'features':[{'type':'Feature','geometry':{'type':'Point','coordinates':[-0.278126,51.5025]},'properties':{'name':'ActonTown'}},{'type':'Feature','geometry':{'type':'Point','coordinates':[-0.263033174,51.50883531]},'properties':{'name':'ActonCentral'}},{'type':'Feature','geometry':{'type':'Point','coordinates':[-0.262879534,51.50856013]},'properties':{'name':'ActonCentral'}}],}];

const ret = undergroundGeoJson.map((u,i) => [
  u.features[i].geometry.coordinates[0],
  u.features[i].geometry.coordinates[1],
]);

console.log(ret);
```

Comment: Thanks for that, it did work. However, I'm only getting the first set of coordinates. Any idea why?

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to access to a property `geometry` of an array `features` which is wrong
So you have to map it like this

```
u.features.map(f => f.geometry.coordinates[0])
```

Your final code should be like this

```js
this.undergroundGeoJson = [{
  'type': 'FeatureCollection',

  'crs': {
    'type': 'name',
    'properties': {
      'name': 'urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84'
    }
  },

  'features': [{
      'type': 'Feature',
      'geometry': {
        'type': 'Point',
        'coordinates': [-0.278126, 51.5025]
      },
      'properties': {
        'name': 'Acton Town'
      }
    },
    {
      'type': 'Feature',
      'geometry': {
        'type': 'Point',
        'coordinates': [-0.263033174, 51.50883531]
      },
      'properties': {
        'name': 'Acton Central'
      }
    },
    {
      'type': 'Feature',
      'geometry': {
        'type': 'Point',
        'coordinates': [-0.262879534, 51.50856013]
      },
      'properties': {
        'name': 'Acton Central'
      }
    }
  ]
}]
function undergroundLatLongs() {
 return this.undergroundGeoJson.map((u) =>
    [u.features.map(f => f.geometry.coordinates[0]), 
    u.features.map(f => f.geometry.coordinates[1])]);
}
console.log(undergroundLatLongs());
```

Answer (score 0):

You were trying to use `.map()` on the `undergroundGeoJson` object. `.map()` can only be used on arrays. I believe you are trying to iterate through the array of objects in `this.undergroundGeoJson.features`?  You have to do this instead:

```
this.undergroundGeoJson.features.map(u => {
   console.log(u) // this will print each object within `features`
   return u; // don't forget to return something
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Since map works in looping through arrays, you can start the mapping from this.undergroundGeoJson[0].features

```js
this.undergroundGeoJson = [{
  'type': 'FeatureCollection',

  'crs': {
    'type': 'name',
    'properties': {
      'name': 'urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84'
    }
  },

  'features': [{
      'type': 'Feature',
      'geometry': {
        'type': 'Point',
        'coordinates': [-0.278126, 51.5025]
      },
      'properties': {
        'name': 'Acton Town'
      }
    },
    {
      'type': 'Feature',
      'geometry': {
        'type': 'Point',
        'coordinates': [-0.263033174, 51.50883531]
      },
      'properties': {
        'name': 'Acton Central'
      }
    },
    {
      'type': 'Feature',
      'geometry': {
        'type': 'Point',
        'coordinates': [-0.262879534, 51.50856013]
      },
      'properties': {
        'name': 'Acton Central'
      }
    }
  ]
}]
function undergroundLatLongs() {
return this.undergroundGeoJson[0].features.map((u) =>
[u.geometry.coordinates[0], 
u.geometry.coordinates[1]]);
}
var x= undergroundLatLongs();
console.log(x);
```

Comment: Will this code may answer the question, an explanation of what you changed would highly help the OP

Comment: You are map function will return undefined, you just want to consol.log, why not try forEach?

Comment: @Treycos Changes made as suggested!

Comment: @Ashish Changes made as suggested!